# How to use string variables with tidy evaluation in ggplot v3.0.0?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I saw that ggplot v3.0.0 now supports tidy evaluation. However, this apparently doesn't allow passing string objects as variable names to ggplot as I can do with dplyr.

```
y_var <- "drat"
```

This works:

```
mtcars %>% select(!!y_var)
```

This doesn't:

```
ggplot(mtcars) + geom_point(aes(x = disp, y = !!y_var))
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are unquoting, but it just yields a character vector.

This works:

```
mtcars %>% select(!!y_var)
```

Because this works:

```
mtcars %>% select('drat')
```

The `?select` help actually states this as an exception:

> ```
> # For convenience it also supports strings and character
> # vectors. This is unlike other verbs where strings would be
> # ambiguous.
> vars <- c(var1 = "cyl", var2 ="am")
> select(mtcars, !!vars)
> rename(mtcars, !!vars)
> ```

It *cannot* be taken as a general working rule for tidy evaluation in the tidyverse.

Case in point, in ggplot character vectors in `aes` have a different meaning, you can't just give:

```
ggplot(mtcars) + geom_point(aes(x = disp, y = 'drat'))
```

Try for example:

```
ggplot(mtcars) + geom_point(aes(x = disp, y = !!as.name(y_var)))
```